# Full URL Required for 404 Page To Work — Apache

Tags: apache-2.4, url, http-status-code-404

On a project I'm working on (currently on localhost on MAMP), the 404 page only works if I include the full URL with the `ErrorDocument` statement in the `.htaccess` file:

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://localhost:8888/project/public/404.php
```

I would like it so that I don't have to manually change this code as and when the site is uploaded from my localhost set up to a live server.

Because the 404 page sits at the same level as the `.htaccess` file in the `public` folder I thought I could use:

```
ErrorDocument 404 404.php
```

But this does not work, and instead just prints `404.php` to the screen when a 404 page should be used.

The folder structure is below, and `project` is the root folder for the site.

```
project
— publicFolder
— privateFolder
```

How do I point the site to the 404.php page, without including the full URL, or in a way that will not need changing then the site is uploaded?

Comment: The `ErrorDocument` path is relative to your `DocumentRoot`, which should be pointed to the `public` folder.

Comment: @ceejayoz I don't understand? Can you give a brief code example?

Comment: Find your server configuration's `DocumentRoot` value. That's where `ErrorDocument` starts looking.

Comment: @ceejayoz I'm using MAMP, and I believe my DocumentRoot is Applications ▹ MAMP ▹ htdocs. On that basis how do I point that to the `public` folder?